# ADCOLONY 2.6.1.1 [info] Ads are not ready for zone

Tags: ios, adcolony

I decided to include ads to my app which is under development and is not yet released. I created two zones in AdColony Dashboard, both are active and in "Show Test Ads only" mode but I still get this message from both in log even though configuration succeeds.

I get this message every single time I run the application. What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a connection issue that is keeping our SDK from communicating with our network.  This could be because the app is monopolizing the network connection or that the device itself is not connected or even that you are not connecting to a stable/strong connection.  If checking your connection status does not reveal the issue, this is most likely a one-off issue that must be worked on through AdColony Support at support@adcolony.com.  When contacting our support, please include a full console log showing all app activity fro when you initialize our SDK through an attempted video view.